# Customize ngTagsInput Autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-tags-input

Anyone knows how to customize the layout of ngTagsInput autocomplete?

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" placeholder="neues Tag">
    <-- Customize this autocomplete layout  --->
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

I want to embed something like this template in the autocomple result

```
<div> {{ Category }} : {{ TagName }} </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in support for custom autoComplete template now.

you can change the default autocomplete template by setting the template option:

```
<auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" template="/path/custom-template"></auto-complete>
```

or

```
<auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" template="my-custom-template"></auto-complete>
```

If using inline template you can specify like this :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-custom-template">
    ...
</script>
```

Official documentation is here.
http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/guides/custom-templates

Answer (score 0):

<s>Currently there's no built-in support for that, but you can always get the source code and customize it to your needs.</s>

There is an open issue for that feature, though. You can keep track of its progress [here](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/99).

[Custom templates](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/guides/custom-templates) are now supported. Irfad Ibrahim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32188030/1349152) provides additional info.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Override the $templateCache by physically having the files on the folder, which for this library would be:

   ```
   $templateCache.put('ngTagsInput/tags-input.html', ' ... '
   $templateCache.put('ngTagsInput/auto-complete.html', ' ... '
   ```
2. Use a template script on your html:

   ```
   <script id="ngTagsInput/tags-input.html" type="text/ng-template">
     <div>Whatever here</div>
   </script>
   ```
3. Inject the `$templateCache` service and override the template on your module

   ```
   angular.module('myApp',[])
     .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache){
       $templateCache.put('ngTagsInput/tags-input.html',
          <div>Whatever here</div>
       );
     }]);
   ```